# max_execution_time always is 0

Tags: php, apache, time, ini

I cant change the value of the property `max_execution_time`.
In the `php.ini` it is set to
`max_execution_time = 13000`.
Also in the `.htaccess`
`php_flag max_execution_time 130000`.
In `phpinfo.php`

```
ini_set('max_execution_time','1300');
set_time_limit(13000);
phpinfo();?>
```

I tried everything and nothing change the value. Using `php-fpm 7.0` with `apache`

Comment: Restarted your server?

Comment: @kerbholz of course he did, after all he said he tried *everything*